# How should I approach this web architecture involving c++ heavy load library and php front end

Tags: php, c++, web-applications, network-programming

I have c++ api that its job is connect to some server , this is the only way I can connect to this server via this c++ lib
Now.   I need to be able to let users to register to web site done in php ( already done no problem here )
For each user I need to run this c++ lib to perform some tasks for the user and return results to the front end (php).
My main question is how to invoke this lib from say Apache server to the back end end back to the front end
Do I need to setup application server in the back to perform the tasks, remember many users could ask for this service?
Thanks

Comment: Can you tell us more about this C++ API?

Comment: its static lib that handle specific xml like protocol to the detestation server i fill it with parameters and the lib preper the API and then i invoke it via http

Comment: PHP is not your front end. HTML and Javascript are your front end. PHP is part of the back end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could enter these tasks into a job system or queue, such as [Gearman](http://gearman.org/). Jobs can be ran synchronously (get the results immediately) or asynchronously (for tasks that take a while and don't need an immediate result sending back to the visitor).

Comment: this is brilliant thanks! tell me please how is the preformens ?

Comment: Performance in an environment like that has so many variables it's impossible to say/guess. The best way to find out is to run a test yourself, in your environment, with realistic data.

Answer (score 0):

As long as they can be executed you can use the PHP `exec()` command